# Android Spinner in DatePicker

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a DatePicker like this one.

[date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ8Og.jpg)

The problem is that When I go in the spinner from December to January it should increment the year by 1, but it does not. How can it be changed?

```
    dpTake=(DatePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dpTake);
    Date dt = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(dt);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    dt = c.getTime();
    dpTake.setMinDate(dt.getTime());
```

Comment: From what i understand from your question it will increment the year by one only when you change the year by clicking on year . clicking month spinner you are just changing the month . May be i have miss understood your question.To increment year by 1 year use this c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

Comment: c.add(Calendar.Date,1) I use because I want the first available choosable date to be the 1 day from the date now. c.add(Calendar.Year, 1) will start the min possible choosable date for the user to be the next year

Comment: for example when I change the spinner to the 31 december, I see on the calendar 31st december, and on the spin to the next month I would like the calendar to pass to the 2017. Is it possible?

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate the problem (unless you are testing it on Dec 31) - because it takes the current date and adds one day. If we can't see the problem, how are we expected to help?

Comment: @Andrew T that is not possible because how will you understand if user wants to go to next year when he spins to the next month or is the user interested in just changing the month only

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works perfectly:

```
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    // this part is equiv to "get date from picker"
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d=null;
    try {
      d=df.parse("2016-12-31");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // this is add-ing
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    // this part is equiv to "set date to picker"
    System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));

    // some more tests
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 29);
    System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));

    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
  }
```

Result:

```
2017-01-01
2017-01-30
2017-02-28
```